# iOS 7 audio remote control

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I implemented a audio player based on MPMoviePlayerController.
It also supported remote control on iOS6 or earlier(remote control can start/pause, next and previous),

In new iOS7, audio remote control can move the currentplaybacktime of audio, but I don't know how to achieve it? Could anyone help me please?

This is screenshot of my audio player remote control, It can show progress of current song, can't adjust it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kciOg.png

This is screenshot of iPad internal music application, It can adjust the currentplaybacktime of songs, just like red circle area
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW0Ou.png

Anyway, many thanks to everyone, thank you.